# Integrating WSO2 IdentityServer and WSO2 API Manager

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IdentityServer 5.11.0 on one machine and WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 on another machine. All the user-level services (User creation, Role assignment, Group, and permissions) should be maintained in IdentityServer, and all Application-level services(like API registration, policy setup, etc). The User creation/Role and Group creation are working fine in IdentityServer using all the necessary RESTful APIs provided by IdentityServer documentation. Once created one user in IdentityServer, how that user should call the services in the WSO2 API manager? I am basically searching for the process of integration between IdentityServer and API manager.

N.B: Below URL is not for IS 5.11.0 and APIM 3.2.0.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

Comment: As you described, we understood that you need to configure the WSO2 IS and WSO2 APIM with each other. You can follow [1] in order to get an idea of how we can configure these two products.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/#configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager

Comment: Thanks Jayathilaka. Following the above URL, please help me on below points:1) [event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://<traffic-manager-host>:<traffic-manager-https-port>/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "WSO2IS" What is <traffic-manager-host>? Is it the IP address of the machine where IS has installed with the port number?

Comment: Please help me to check below stackover link                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65787820/wso2-identityserver-5-11-and-wso2-api-management-3-2-0-integration-have-db-scrip