# WSO2 IdentityServer 5.11 and WSO2 API Management 3.2.0 integration have DB script issue

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Following the below URL
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/#step-4-configure-wso2-is-with-wso2-api-m
When I am trying to configure WSO2 IS 5.11.0 and WSO2 APIM 3.2.0, found below issues

1. The table alternation sql commands are not working until removing AUTO_INCREMENT tag.
   The sql commands are
   shared_db

---

ALTER TABLE REG_RESOURCE_COMMENT ADD COLUMN REG_RESOURCE_COMMENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE REG_RESOURCE_PROPERTY ADD COLUMN REG_RESOURCE_PROPERTY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE REG_RESOURCE_RATING ADD COLUMN REG_RESOURCE_RATING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE REG_RESOURCE_TAG ADD COLUMN REG_RESOURCE_TAG_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE ADD COLUMN UM_SHARED_USER_ROLE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

apim_db;
ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_AUDIT ADD COLUMN IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_AUDIT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_BINDING ADD COLUMN IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_BINDING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE IDN_AUTH_USER_SESSION_MAPPING ADD COLUMN IDN_AUTH_USER_SESSION_MAPPING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE IDN_OAUTH2_CIBA_REQUEST_SCOPES ADD COLUMN IDN_OAUTH2_CIBA_REQUEST_SCOPES_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE CM_SP_PURPOSE_PURPOSE_CAT_ASSC ADD COLUMN CM_SP_PURPOSE_PURPOSE_CAT_ASSC_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE CM_PURPOSE_PII_CAT_ASSOC ADD COLUMN CM_PURPOSE_PII_CAT_ASSOC_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE CM_SP_PURPOSE_PII_CAT_ASSOC ADD COLUMN CM_SP_PURPOSE_PII_CAT_ASSOC_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE CM_CONSENT_RECEIPT_PROPERTY ADD COLUMN CM_CONSENT_RECEIPT_PROPERTY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

N.B: These sql commnads are not working until removing AUTO_INCREMENT tag. Please suggest, is it ok to remove AUTO_INCREMENT tag from above sql commands?

2. Starting IS, I am getting below error messages in log.
   [2021-01-19 16:08:07,649] []  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator} - Unable to load transports from the registry. Some transports may not get initialized. org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to add properties to the resource /_system/config/repository/transports/http/listener. Field 'REG_VERSION' doesn't have a default value
   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:299)
   at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2505)

Please suggest, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [product compatibility page](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/reference/product-compatibility/#compatible-wso2-identity-server-as-the-key-managers) it looks like the products wso2am3.2.0 and wso2is5.11.0 are not compatible.

It also looks like wso2 documentation was inconsistent when you were trying configure your environment.

You can try configure your key manager in another way, look at that [documentation page](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/)